# Writing an Excel spreadsheet with Python3

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Hello I want to write some of my data from my program to a spreadsheet. I am running python3 and have installed **xlsxwriter** package.

But totally new to **xlsxwriter**

Here is my dict which I want to write as spreadsheet.

```
[
    { 
        'name': 'xyz', 
        'data': [
            { 
                'price': '$29.95', 'service': 'website'
            },
            { 
                'price': '$7.08', 'service': 'network'
            }
        ], 
        'total': '$37.03',
        'start_date': '2020-12-01',
        'end_date': '2020-12-01'
    },
    { 
        'name': 'test', 
        'data': [
            { 
                'price': '$112.43', 'service': 'website'
            },
            { 
                'price': '$188.82', 'service': 'network'
            }
        ], 
        'total': '$301.25',
        'start_date': '2020-12-01',
        'end_date': '2020-12-01'
    }
]
```

and here is the output that I want.

[image]

Would you please help me how I can do this **xlsxwriter**

Comment: I would recommend using the python openpyxl module for this

Answer (score 1):

You can make rows based on the content you want, and then iterate over them to write to the document. The following code makes a file called `xlsxwriter_test.xlsx`. Then creates a tuple with the rows. It then iterates over the rows, writes to the document, then closes it.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("xlsxwriter_test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

rows = (
    ["Client Name", "Service", "Price", "Start Date", "End Date", "Total"],
    ["xyz", "website", "$29.95", "12/1/20", "12/31/20", "37.03"],
    [None, "network", "$7.08", "12/1/20", "12/31/20", None],
    [None,None,None,None,None,None],
    ["test", "website", "$112.43", "12/1/20", "12/31/20", "301.25"],
    [None, "network", "$188.82", "12/1/20", "12/31/20", None]
)
row = 0

for name, service, price, startD, endD,total in (rows):
    col = 0
    worksheet.write(row,col, name)
    col += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col, service)
    col += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col, price)
    col += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col, startD)
    col += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col, endD)
    col += 1
    worksheet.write(row,col, total)
    row+=1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: How I can convert my dict into this rows []

Comment: I'm not sure, but somebody might be able to help you if you post another question.